# Joining multiple fields to one in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

#### tblItinerary

```
ID | Place1 | Time1 | Place2 | Time2 | Place3 | Time3 |
1  | 1      |   10  |   2    |   23  |    1   |   21  |
2  | 2      |   5   |   3    |   4   |    1   |   12  |
```

#### tblPlaces

```
ID | PlaceName |
1  | Austria   |
2  | Germany   |
3  | India     |
```

I want do a `WHERE tblItinerary = 1` to see the result set as:

```
Place1  | Place2  | Place3  |
Austria | Germany | Austria |
```

Right now the direction I have is something like

```
SELECT tblPlaces.PlaceName
 FROM tblPlaces
 JOIN tblPlaces.PlaceName
 ON tblItinerary.Place1 = tblPlaces.PlaceName
 JOIN tblPlaces.PlaceName
 ON tblItinerary.Place2 = tblPlaces.PlaceName
 JOIN tblPlaces.PlaceName
 ON tblItinerary.Place3 = tblPlaces.PlaceName
 WHERE tblItinerary.ID = 1;
```

Comment: You will have to alias the table you join to, if you are going to join to it multiple times.

Comment: Oracle. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is correct, but there are some mistakes: to join one table multiple times, you should use unique aliases for each table. Also, you have not actually joined `tblItinerary` anywhere and your join syntax is incorrect (your attempt to join `tblPlaces.PlaceName` instead of `tblPlaces`). Try the following:

```
select p1.PlaceName as Place1
     , p2.PlaceName as Place2
     , p3.PlaceName as Place3
from tblItinerary i
join tblPlaces p1 on i.Place1 = p1.ID
join tblPlaces p2 on i.Place2 = p2.ID
join tblPlaces p3 on i.Place3 = p3.ID
where i.ID = 1;
```

Comment: imo, would be less confusing with 'column alias' of  `p1.PlaceName as PlaceName1` etc. The current `Place1` column alias matches a different data item causing 'confusion'? The code is correct. I will delete this comment later.

Comment: @RyanVincent: Maybe you are right, but I was just sticking to the provided desired output. So don't delete your comment, it should clarify possible confusion.